# Ignore a property when saving a POCO in MongoDB, but not ignoring it when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I have the following model that I'm storing in MongoDB:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Int PersonId { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument Resume { get; set; } // arbitrary JSON

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    // stored elsewhere, 
                                             // populated at runtime
    [BsonIgnore]
    public string LastName { get; set; }     // ditto
}
```

`Resume` is a `BsonDocument` where I store arbitrary JSON that cannot be standardized into a POCO (each occurrence is vastly different).

I don't want to store the person's first and last names since that information is already stored in a SQL database and I don't want to have to worry about syncing changes. So I've decorated those parameters with `[BsonIgnore]`. When my app code retrieves the `Person` from MongoDB it populates the `FirstName` and `LastName` parameters before serializing it to JSON, like so:

```
public ActionResult GetPerson(int id)
{
    var query = New QueryDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
    // personCollection is Collection<Person>
    var person = personCollection.FindOne(query);

    var pc = personCache.GetPerson(person.PersonId);

    person.FirstName = pc.FirstName;
    person.LastName = pc.LastName;

    var settings = New JsonWriterSettings() { Outputmode = JsonOutputMode.Strict }
    return Json(person.ToJson(settings), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The resulting JSON, however, is missing `FirstName` and `LastName` nodes, apparently because they were decorated with `[BsonIgnore]`.

**Is there a way to tell the [Official MongoDB C# driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) to ignore saving the parameters in MongoDB but not ignore it when serializing into JSON?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's possible while you're using the driver itself to serialize your objects into `json`.

**However** you can (and probably should) use [`json.net`](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to serialize into `json`. That way your `BsonIgnore` will have no effect on `json` serialization and the `json` attributes (like `JsonIgnore`) will have no effect on your mongo driver.

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    publis string FullName {get; set;}
    [BsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnore]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In my opinion that will also be a better design because the `bson` is used for the DB and the `json` (mostly) is used for web consumption, and so be done using different tools.

Comment: The MongoDB C# driver can serialize into JSON. It adds a `.ToJson` extension method. As for using Json.NET, that is a good idea but it won't work out of the box when serializing Mongo types. I was able to figure it out and posted an answer. I'm marking yours as the answer.

Comment: @Paperjam yes. of course it can. I meant that while mongo db uses bson it "helps" you to serialize json. but if you're using json for web, you might want a robust dedicated framework for it. Thanks anyway...

Comment: While you can *output* using Json.Net, you cannot *round-trip* the data if you use sub-classing, as it does not include the class hierarchy that the Mongo serializer does.

Comment: @crashmstr you can configure the serializer to add that information in the `$type` property (see [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm))

Answer (score 4):

I decided to take I3arnon's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23453806/118697) and use Json.NET. The problem is Json.NET doesn't know how to handle most Mongo types, so serializing the `Resume` property was problematic because it's of type `BsonDocument`. Here's what I came up with:

Json.NET can normally serialize the result of a Mongo query, however the `BsonDocument` gave it a problem. In the case of my example, Json.NET could not serialize `Person` without special instructions on how to handle a `BsonDocument`.

First, I created a `JsonConverter` called *BsonDocumentConverter*:

```
public class BsonDocumentConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var settings = new JsonWriterSettings()
        {
            OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict
        };

        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToJson(settings));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Why would I want to deserialize?");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(BsonDocument);
    }
}
```

This converter uses the MongoDB C# driver to serialize any BsonDocuments.

To use the converter:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.None, 
                 new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                     Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { 
                         new BsonDocumentConverter() 
                         } 
                 });

return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [NotMapped] attribute for firstname and lastname properties and remove [BsonIgnore] attribute. It will work

Comment: I believe `[NotMapped]` is an Entity Framework attribute. It has no effect in MongoDB.

Comment: [NotMapped] is System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema attribute. Please look into this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx and try it.

Comment: Using `[NotMapped]` on the two parameters I don't want in MongoDB has no effect. The parameters still show up in the document.